# how to allocate go blocks to threads in core.asyc

Tags: clojure, core.async

I've been working with core.async for a little bit (server side) and have a question regarding allocating threads to a core.asyc go loop.

If i had the following go-block

```
(go (while true
  (let [[v ch] (alts!! [@app/p4])]
    (when (= :notify (:action v))
      (do-notify v)))))
```

I see that this and all other go blocks are tying up the same thread that i call this function on.

I've tried this:

```
(dotimes [i 10]
      (.start (Thread.
               (fn []
                 (go (while true
                   (let [[v ch] (alts!! [@app/p4])]
                     (when (= :notify (:action v))
                       (do-notify v)))))))))
```

and while it "works" i feel like i'm unnecessarily tying up threads and not taking advantage of the flexible nature of channels. What is the clojure way of spinning up threads on demand with a limit using core.async ?

Comment: This is actually exactly what core.async does. It has a Threadpool. You might see the same threads since you're not using them enough. https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/exec/threadpool.clj

Comment: to be clear, core.async does not and cannot allocate threads for this code, because it uses `alts!!` which hogs a thread, instead of `alts!` which allows thread reuse between go blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alts!!` blocks the thread. Inside go blocks, you want to use `alts!`, which will park it (aka, free it so it can run other go blocks)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is essentially right. It's so right in fact that it's almost exactly what the [`thread`](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/a6dc01d2ebb692a39e923988b0853ff2bd1a431b/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async.clj#L441) macro does.

A easier way of expressing the same idea would be simply:

`(dotimes [i 10]
      (thread
         (go (while true
                (let [[v ch] (alts! [@app/p4])]
                  (when (= :notify (:action v))
                     (do-notify v)))))))`